# Media query not working properly (Media query link after css styling)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

[image]

Hey guys,

I have attached a photo to show and figure out why my media query is not working properly. In this photo I want to show you that I want to make a contact page and I have styled it in HTML and in CSS. After completing styling I want to make it responsive, so I used media query. But as shown in the picture, it is coming after css which is affecting my media query and block it to make it responsive. I just want to know why this is happening. I have also checked linking and asset target but I am unable to figure it out to solve this problem. So guys, please help me to solve this error.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the media query at the bottom of your CSS file? Remember that CSS is cascading so the media queries should be after all the general applied styles so it overwrites the style correctly.

Comment: No, I have used different file for media query. And also for linking that page I have linked after style.css

Comment: as stated by @EdgarReynaga. You need to make sure the media query reference is at the bottommost so it will be able to overwrite previous ones. Or you can force it to apply with '! important' behind the attributes.

Comment: This is also relevant if you are linking the stylesheet in your head. So you should load the media query style sheet after your basic stylesheet.

Comment: It is just above the title

Comment: I don't want to use "!important" tag.

Comment: You also do not need to set a min/max width if you are starting with 0px. Your media query should just read: @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { }

Comment: @EdgarReynaga now also it is not working

Comment: Is your viewport set in your head? ex: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: The viewport is used when rendering responsive pages and is therefore mostly used when dealing with mobile websites, but when dealing with media queries it helps tell the CSS what the actual device width is.

Comment: Below is my HTML

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/media.css">
    <title>Online World Solution</title>
</head>

Comment: Hey guys, I've solved it myself. I found that a page I linked via php did not have the media query I linked in that page. I didn't link media query in that page because I didn't make it responsive.

Comment: Also, you were missing some { }

Comment: @CarolMcKay I don't think so, also I have checked and none of any braces are missing. But thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Once you should try in the media query css property**

```
width:100% !important;
```

sometimes css property clashes with same selector in property

> When it comes then you should define in property as important in css